# Is it possible to obtain a type's summary using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

you know how when you go to object browser and you select a type there is a summary below its name?

For example:

```
public sealed class Activator
     Member of System

 Summary:
  Contains methods to create types of objects locally or remotely, or obtain references to existing remote objects. This class cannot be inherited.
```

Is it possible to obtain that information using Reflection? If so, how is it done? If that's not possible, where is that data stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the comments `can’t be discovered by reflection` alone is because they are `not included in the .NET assemblies` (.EXE or .DLL files), but are conventionally `included as .XML files to accompany the assembly files`.

`DocsByReflection` can be used to get the summary. Refer to the link [here](http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=49) for details.

Answer (score 2):

And the answer is:

http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=49

Looks like it is possible.

Comment: _Technically_, this isn't using reflection to get the docs - it is loading the docs from the associated XML file.

Comment: @adrianbanks: Well, summary (or comments) aren't included at compile time. So if the question is ONLY with reflection, then the asnwer is "No."